# Outlook internal browser does not open deeplink on IOS

Tags: ios, outlook, deep-linking

We have the following functionality: We send a user an email with a deeplink button in it, which redirects the user to a webpage, which redirects to our mobile application where they are automatically logged in. We got a mail a few days ago from one of our users who used outlook on an iphone, which did not open the link. After some investigation we found out that the in-app browser for outlook returns an error when we try to open the deeplink (the in-app browser seems to be a dumbed-down version of Edge). This only happens on IOS though, android works fine. I'm wondering if anyone has run into this issue before, and if anyone has a fix which will not inconvienence our users.

[image: Error in dutch]

Translates to:
Can't open page
This page can't currently be loaded.
Please try again later.

Comment: What is the exact error returned by the browser?

Comment: Added it to the original post.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, I think this has happened to us as well.
The workaround is the user to copy-paste link in browser

Comment: Hey bro, i am facing this problem so kindly if u have the solution and tell me then it will save my searching time so kindly give the solution here.
Thanks

Comment: We changed our flow for this particular case, we did not find a solution for it at all sadly.